# How to fix Error "Non-exhaustive patterns" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have some problem with my code, I'm trying to put a color into a list of colors depending of a list of centroids.
I've got a non-matching pattern but i don't understand why?
Could you help me?

Best Regard
(Sorry for my English level)

```
verifWhereShouldGo :: Colors -> [Float] -> Float -> Int -> [[Colors]] -> [[Colors]]
verifWhereShouldGo    _ _ _ 525 newListCluster = newListCluster
verifWhereShouldGo    _ [] d_anc _ newListCluster = newListCluster
verifWhereShouldGo    couleur (firstD:restD) d_anc counter (fristList:restList) = do
   case firstD <= d_anc of
    True -> do
        let try = (fristList ++ [couleur])
        verifWhereShouldGo couleur (firstD:restD) 0 525 (try:restList)
    False -> do
        let d_anc = firstD
        verifWhereShouldGo couleur restD d_anc 1 restList
```

Comment: You assume that the fifth argument is non-empty when the second is—this is not guaranteed to be true.

Comment: yes, I try to find more precisly where the error come from and there it is : FUN_imageCompressor_2018/app/Main.hs:77:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘verifWhereShouldGo’:
        Patterns not matched: _ (_:_) _ p [] where p is not one of {525}
   |
77 | verifWhereShouldGo _ _ _ 525 newListCluster = newListCluster

Comment: I have told you precisely where it comes from. You need to add a line along the lines of `verifWhereShouldGo a (x:xs) b c [] = ...`, that's it.

Comment: Ow, yes! Thank you for you fast answer.